# How to change the column header name in Linux

Tags: linux, awk

I want to switch this:

```
**hg19chrc  snpid   a1  a2  bp  info    or  se  p   ngt**
chr1    rs4951859   C   G   729679  0.631   0.97853 0.0173  0.2083  0
chr1    rs142557973 T   C   731718  0.665   1.01949 0.0198  0.3298  0
chr1    rs141242758 T   C   734349  0.666   1.02071 0.02    0.3055  0
```

into this:

```
**CHR     SNP           A1  A2  BP      info    OR      se        p     ngt**
chr1    rs4951859   C   G   729679  0.631   0.97853 0.0173  0.2083  0
chr1    rs142557973 T   C   731718  0.665   1.01949 0.0198  0.3298  0
chr1    rs141242758 T   C   734349  0.666   1.02071 0.02    0.3055  0
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Plain text file? Easiest is to slap the new starting line (header) on to the tail:

```
(echo "your header here"; tail -n +2 file) > outfile
```